# Scrolling Jscrollpane by dragging content inside container?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I was wondering, would it be possible to scroll content by clicking and dragging on it like you would with your finger on an iPhone?

[Here's a Jscrollpane example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHvHb/2/)

I thought about extending the scrollbar over the whole region and making it invisible, however I would like to maintain layer click functionality inside.

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="MenuList" class="scroll-pane">
        <div id="somelayer-one" onclick="alert('Jquery Function');">text</div>
</div></div>
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

**Additional info**

I tried looking into the original plugin and tried to modify this:

```
function initialiseVerticalScroll()
            {
                if (isScrollableV) {

                    container.append(
                        $('<div class="jspVerticalBar" />').append(
                            $('<div class="jspCap jspCapTop" />'),
                            $('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(
                                $('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(
                                    $('<div class="jspDragTop" />'),
                                    $('<div class="jspDragBottom" />')
                                )
                            ),
                            $('<div class="jspCap jspCapBottom" />')
                        )
                    );

                    verticalBar = container.find('>.jspVerticalBar');
                    verticalTrack = verticalBar.find('>.jspTrack');
                    verticalDrag = verticalTrack.find('>.jspDrag');

                    if (settings.showArrows) {
                        arrowUp = $('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowUp" />').bind(
                            'mousedown.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, -1)
                        ).bind('click.jsp', nil);
                        arrowDown = $('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowDown" />').bind(
                            'mousedown.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, 1)
                        ).bind('click.jsp', nil);
                        if (settings.arrowScrollOnHover) {
                            arrowUp.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, -1, arrowUp));
                            arrowDown.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown));
                        }

                        appendArrows(verticalTrack, settings.verticalArrowPositions, arrowUp, arrowDown);
                    }

                    verticalTrackHeight = paneHeight;
                    container.find('>.jspVerticalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspVerticalBar>.jspArrow').each(
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalTrackHeight -= $(this).outerHeight();
                        }
                    );


                    verticalDrag.hover(
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalDrag.addClass('jspHover');
                        },
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalDrag.removeClass('jspHover');
                        }
                    ).bind(
                        'mousedown.jsp',
                        function(e)
                        {
                            // Stop IE from allowing text selection
                            $('html').bind('dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp', nil);

                            verticalDrag.addClass('jspActive');

                            var startY = e.pageY - verticalDrag.position().top;

                            $('html').bind(
                                'mousemove.jsp',
                                function(e)
                                {
                                    positionDragY(e.pageY - startY, false);
                                }
                            ).bind('mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp', cancelDrag);
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                    sizeVerticalScrollbar();
                }
            }
```

I changed `verticalDrag = verticalTrack.find('>.jspDrag');` to `verticalDrag = verticalTrack.find('>#somelayer-one');`, however that did not work for some reason. However, I think that if changed properly - this might work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this something you want http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/sortables.html

Comment: Hi Palash, Thanks, but I was looking for something along the lines of what hongaar and Gianni posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. is it what you are looking for?

```
function initialiseVerticalScroll()
            {
                if (isScrollableV) {

                    container.append(
                        $('<div class="jspVerticalBar" />').append(
                            $('<div class="jspCap jspCapTop" />'),
                            $('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(
                                $('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(
                                    $('<div class="jspDragTop" />'),
                                    $('<div class="jspDragBottom" />')
                                )
                            ),
                            $('<div class="jspCap jspCapBottom" />')
                        )
                    );

                    verticalBar = container.find('>.jspVerticalBar');
                    /* ADDED CODE */
                    verticalBar.width(0);
                    /* ADDED CODE */
                    verticalTrack = verticalBar.find('>.jspTrack');
                    verticalDrag = verticalTrack.find('>.jspDrag');

                    if (settings.showArrows) {
                        arrowUp = $('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowUp" />').bind(
                            'mousedown.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, -1)
                        ).bind('click.jsp', nil);
                        arrowDown = $('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowDown" />').bind(
                            'mousedown.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, 1)
                        ).bind('click.jsp', nil);
                        if (settings.arrowScrollOnHover) {
                            arrowUp.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, -1, arrowUp));
                            arrowDown.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown));
                        }

                        appendArrows(verticalTrack, settings.verticalArrowPositions, arrowUp, arrowDown);
                    }

                    verticalTrackHeight = paneHeight;
                    container.find('>.jspVerticalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspVerticalBar>.jspArrow').each(
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalTrackHeight -= $(this).outerHeight();
                        }
                    );


                    verticalDrag.hover(
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalDrag.addClass('jspHover');
                        },
                        function()
                        {
                            verticalDrag.removeClass('jspHover');
                        }
                    ).bind(
                        'mousedown.jsp',
                        function(e)
                        {
                            // Stop IE from allowing text selection
                            $('html').bind('dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp', nil);

                            verticalDrag.addClass('jspActive');

                            var startY = e.pageY - verticalDrag.position().top;

                            $('html').bind(
                                'mousemove.jsp',
                                function(e)
                                {
                                    positionDragY(e.pageY - startY, false);
                                }
                            ).bind('mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp', cancelDrag);
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                    /* ADDED CODE */
                    container.bind("mousedown.jsp", function (e) 
                { 
                    // Stop IE from allowing text selection
                    $('html').bind('dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp', nil);

                    var startY = verticalDrag.position().top;
                    var initialY = e.pageY;
                    $('html').bind(
                        'mousemove.jsp',
                        function(e)
                        {
                            positionDragY(startY - (e.pageY - initialY), false);
                        }
                    ).bind('mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp', cancelDrag);
                    return false;
                });
                    /* ADDED CODE */
                    sizeVerticalScrollbar();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Gianni! It's exactly what I was looking for :))) Do you think I could make the scrolling inverted though? I tried changing the minuses to the pluses - but then I noticed that it seems the code is binded to the mouse position.

Comment: You're welcome :) I was trying to invert the scrolling direction. I tried to change positionDragY(e.pageY - startY, false); with positionDragY(startY - e.pageY, false); but the scrolling works only from top to bottom. I'll make a check to see if i could solve the problem

Comment: U are simply the best! Thank you Gianni

Answer (score 4):

Extending the scrollbar and making it invisible. I'm pretty sure that would be a lot more difficult to achieve than what you're asking. It's probably been done a million times and possibly draggable() would work... but without any plugins:

CSS

```
#maincontainer
{
    position:absolute;
}​
```

jQuery

```
$('#maincontainer').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $(this).data('held', e.screenY - $(this).offset().top);
}).on('mouseup', function(){
    $(this).data('held', false);
}).on('mousemove', function(e){
    if ($(this).data('held')!=false) $(this).css({top:e.screenY - $(this).data('held')});
});​
```

edit: using your html, this http://jsfiddle.net/apDrX/1/

Comment: Hi popnoodles. Thanks for your answer - so what you're saying is that I cannot use your code with the JsScrollpane plugin? I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/apDrX/3/) and noticed it's a no go. Edit: The reason why I'm asking is because I also like the idea of a scrollbar being there too.

Comment: It works but you've missed the important position:absolute - if you look at what my code does you see it positions the element on the page. And you've given all your elements the same id. Id's must be unique. Use a class for a common identifier. With those two things fixed it works. http://jsfiddle.net/apDrX/4/

Comment: but try the other answer which uses jScrollPane too

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, however this solution still breaks my original jScrollPane - [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/apDrX/5/). With this solution, I could somehow overcome the `position: absolute` to place multiple items under each other - however as you can see I tried to insert a second item under the current one - and the scrollbar on the right doesn't seem to function properly. In addition to that, the div inside the container doesn't scroll the whole thing, but rather moves itself without moving the other items around it.

Comment: this is going to be something that should use jscrollpane's func to control. I would suggest asking the developers instead.

Comment: I will write them an email. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kHvHb/5/

```
​var scroll = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
var api = scroll.data('jsp');


$('.jspPane div').mouseup(function(){
    var miY = $(this).position().top + $('.jspPane').position().top
    console.log( $('.jspPane').position().top);
    api.scrollTo(0,miY);
    return false
})

​
```

Comment: Hi karacas, I tried that with both firefox 16 and IE 8 and it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer as it doesn't describe adjusting jScrollPane, **BUT** I would recommend using the (incredible powerful) plugin called [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), **IF** it is an option to switch plugins.

It does pretty much the same job, let's you customize the scrollbar (as with jScrollPane), is compatible with mobile browsers, uses hardware accelerated CSS transforms where available, retains click functionality in its container, etc.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4